# How do I set the AE Title on a server I'm creating?

Tags: c#, uwp, fo-dicom

I'm making a *very* simple STORE server, that isn't intended to do anything DICOM-like other than echo and take in data. I'm inheriting from `DicomCEchoProvider` and letting the parent class do most of the work for me: the only methods that so far have any planned use are `DicomCStoreResponse()` and `OnCStoreRequestException()`, from the `IDicomCStoreProvider` interface.

My test-machine doesn't seem to care about the AET at all, but I can't presume every other machine will be so accommodating. How can I set the AE Title to something of my choosing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server (SCP) does not send an AETitle. Instead the SCU sends both the calling AET and the called AET via Association Request (on handshake). Its the job of the SCP to check this data and then accept or reject the association.
If you do not code something explicitly, then by default the SCP accepts every association.

Take a look at the samples-project (https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom-samples/blob/master/Desktop/C-Store%20SCP/Program.cs).
You have to create your own class inheriting from `DicomService`, and there in method `OnReceiveAssociationRequestAsync` you have to code something like that:

```
        public Task OnReceiveAssociationRequestAsync(DicomAssociation association)
        {
            // here you can check for the AETitle. You can also handle various AETitles and implement different behaviour depending on the AETitle (thats common in real PACS systems), like storing the files on different drives depending on the called AETitle...
            if (association.CalledAE != "STORESCP")
            {
                return SendAssociationRejectAsync(
                    DicomRejectResult.Permanent,
                    DicomRejectSource.ServiceUser,
                    DicomRejectReason.CalledAENotRecognized);
            }

            foreach (var pc in association.PresentationContexts)
            {
                if (pc.AbstractSyntax == DicomUID.Verification) pc.AcceptTransferSyntaxes(AcceptedTransferSyntaxes);
                else if (pc.AbstractSyntax.StorageCategory != DicomStorageCategory.None) pc.AcceptTransferSyntaxes(AcceptedImageTransferSyntaxes);
            }

            return SendAssociationAcceptAsync(association);
        }
```